# Android studio build failed debug/out error

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I use react-native 0.61.5 and android studio 3.6.3, when run app have issue:  Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
198 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 191 up-to-date
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/xxx/Projects/reactnative/xxx/android/app/build/intermediates/external_file_lib_dex_archives/debug/out
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `android` folder delete `.gradle` folder, then run the command below on your project root folder

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```